# Brownian Motion with drift away from the origin

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Does there exist a process which, when it is positive behaves like Brownian motion with drift $\mu >0$ and when it is negative like Brownian motion with drift $-\mu<0$? I.e., Brownian motion with drift away from the origin.

It would have an SDE:
$$
dX_t = \mu \times \text{sign}(X_t)dt + dB_t
$$
but I'm aware that $\text{sign}(x)$is not a Lipschitz function so we can't apply the classic existence result.

Can we say that a process $|X_t|$ exists with drift $\mu$ and behaviour like a reflected Brownian motion? If so, what does the SDE look like? How would I calculate something like $\mathbb{P}(|X_t|\leq r)$?

I don't really know where to begin, but I think it should be true that the probability distribution function of $|X_t|$ is the solution of some partial differential equation (like the pdf of $|B_t|$ is when $B$ is Brownian motion without drift, but as is not the case for $|B_t|$ with the usual omni-directional drift.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Existence of solutions to SDEs with ill-behaved coefficients is of course a quesiton, you could check this https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039617300840. If the solution does not exist in a strong or weak sense, there's not much that can be done with that

Comment: You can get a weak solution using the Girsanov theorem. An example how to do it is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/243809/340165).

Comment: @KurtG. in the example you give, the $dB_t$ term is multiplied by $X_t$, but not here... Is it obvious how to extend?

Comment: I have since found references for the SDE: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Goran.Peskir/law.pdf, and, following their reference, in Graversen and Shiryaev (2000)